# JQuery - appending variable to URL, and use it in a href

Tags: jquery, url, variables, append, href

I can't figure this one out...

Could someone please help me en explain how it works to?

Goal:
Adding a variable to a hard-coded URL, and put the new string into a href

Example:

```
var x = "1000";
var y = "http://www.google.com"
var result = y + x;

<a href="! the value of result !">click here...</a>
```

Edit i'm sorry i meant y + x ofcourse...

Comment: "1000http://www.google.com" is quite a strange url...

Comment: Really? -> `'<a href="' + result + '">click here...</a>'`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/

Answer (score 4):

Given this HTML code:
    `<a href="" target="_blank">click here...</a>`

You would need this bit of js code:
(working example http://jsfiddle.net/QUEZL)

```
var x = "http://www.google.com/"
var y = "#q=test";

var result = x + y;
$('a').attr('href', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("a").attr("href", result)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, all the above approaches were replacing the variable with the latest value of the variable as it was referred in a loop.

Solution:

```
  $.each(statusForUI, function( key, value ) {
        x = "http://192.168.10.100:8888/workflow/" + key;
        $('.listTable').append(
                                 '<tr><td>'  +
                                 '<a href="' + x + '"> env_name </a>' + 
                                  key        + 
                                 '</ td></tr>' 
                               );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

HREF is an attribute so you can access it via `.attr()`

```
var x = "1000";
var y = "http://www.google.com/"
var result = y + x;

$('a').attr({'href':result});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give your Link an ID.

   `<a id="lnkTarget" href="#">click here...</a>`
2. Add a reference to JQuery JavaScript Library.

   `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`
3. Get a handle on the link with a JQuery Selector and use the attr function.

   `$('#lnkTarget').attr('href', result);`

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href = result ;
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("a").attr("href", result)
```