# Using jQuery to pass a parameter to an A HTML object (basically, a url, or HREF) - how?

Tags: jquery, html

I've already read these:

[JQuery - appending variable to URL, and use it in a href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334601/jquery-appending-variable-to-url-and-use-it-in-a-href)

[passing variable value to href argument in anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963058/passing-variable-value-to-href-argument-in-anchor-tag)

I'm doing the Random Quote Generator challenge from Free Code Camp. I need to be able to tweet the quote out, so the url needs to dynamically generate with the quote in it.

At the moment I'm on:

jQuery:

```
var tweeturl = 'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=\"' + val.Quotation + '\"" - ' + val.Quotee;
$('a').attr('href', tweeturl);
```

HTML:
    `<a href="" class="btn btn-large"><i class="fa fa-twitter icon-2x"></i>Tweet this quote</a>`

This creates a link, but on codepen this link is: `http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/9dda6df1e553faa3c7a252865ea3fb4f1464125909489/index.html?editors=1010` so definitely not what I'm after.

Other solutions that failed:

1) Having the href in the HTML as `href="#"` (same result)

2) Having the attr part as `$('a').attr({'href', tweeturl});` (extra squiggly brackets) - codepen gives an error and won't run it

3) One guy said in the jQuery to have `$('#a_tag_id').attr('href','http://www.google.com&jobid='+id);` (the second parameter is from the other page, obv. mine would be `tweeturl`) but he never specifies what to do about the A tag in the HTML. The person asking the question had `<a id="a_tag_id">something_here</a>` but, without any href value, the button doesn't even show a location in the bottom left of the browser when you hover over. Adding an empty href value yields the same location as above, the codepen boomerang thing. Also, having `<a id="#a_tag_id">something_here</a>` with the added # doesn't work either.

Can anybody help? Cheers.

Comment: Something that might have something to do with it...  Immediately after the two jQuery lines that I've shown I have `$(".quote").html(html);` This doesn't return a value if the two previous lines are present. However, if I take this line out, it still shows the codepen boomerang thing as the url.

Comment: Here's a link to the pen if anybody wants to see it http://codepen.io/thomasdean/pen/qZGQxK?editors=1010

Comment: val is not defined

Comment: @Grisza. Interesting... does that mean it should be in the json.forEach function?
Edit: that looks like the case. Thanks.

Comment: add `val` to JSON as a name of array http://codepen.io/grzesiekmq/pen/xOKbLz.js now `val` is defined

Answer (score 0):

Append the link itself in proper area, do not just add the `href`. Something  like this...

Edit based on [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasdean/pen/qZGQxK?editors=1010) example

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class = "row text-center">
        <h2>Random Quote Generator</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 quote">
            <h2>"Press the Quote button for a new quote"</h2>
            <h2>Tom Dean</h2>
        </div>
    <div>

    <div class = "row text-center">
        <div class = "col-xs-12">
            <button id = "getQuote" class = "btn btn-large">
                Quote me happy!
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "row text-center">
        <div class = "col-xs-12">
            <div id="tweetitout">
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // if these are in the getJSON function then it doesn't prevent the same quote being shown twice

    var lastQuote = "";
    var whichQuoteToChoose = "";

    $("#getQuote").on("click", function() {
      $.getJSON("http://codepen.io/thomasdean/pen/Yqmgyx.js", function(json) {

        var html = "";

        // this while loop and lastQuote assignment prevents the same quote twice in a row

        while (whichQuoteToChoose === lastQuote) {
          whichQuoteToChoose = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12); // returns a number between 0 and 11
        }
        lastQuote = whichQuoteToChoose;

        // this converts raw data into html. The filter makes it only return one value

        json = json.filter(function(val) {
          return (val.id == whichQuoteToChoose);
        });

        json.forEach(function(val) {

          html += "<div class = 'quote'>"

          html += "<h2>\"" + val.Quotation + "\"</h2><h2>" + val.Quotee + "</h2>"

          html += "</div>"

          var tweeturl = 'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(val.Quotation + ' - ' + val.Quotee);

          $('#tweetitout').html('<a href="'+tweeturl+'" class="btn btn-large"><i class="fa fa-twitter icon-2x"></i>Tweet this quote</a>');
        });



        $(".quote").html(html); // this doesn't work if the previous two lines are present. Why?

      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Ok, but when I do that, what should the HTML look like? If I create  `<div class="#myDiv"></div>` with nothing in it, no button appears. (or remove the #, same thing)

Is this to do with the quotation marks in the href somehow? I'm trying to sort that out with the \ at the moment...

Comment: you want to add something to url on click of button @keeperoftheflame ?

Comment: I think I have an idea of the issue... I want to tweet out a quote. However, this quote can't be tweeted out, because, when the code to create the link is in the JS file in codepen, this stops the get quote button from working. So, it can't return a value. More complicated than I expected.

Comment: I'm doing the Random Quote Generator challenge from Free Code Camp. I need to be able to tweet the quote out, `so the url needs to dynamically generate with the quote in it`. Dynamically yes... How...? on a button click event those links are created?

Comment: or you simply create links via a loop for example and pass them to the appropriate elements @keeperoftheflame

Comment: The issue now appears to be as I wrote in the comment on my question... that `$(".quote").html(html);` doesn't work with the other two lines of code present. Any idea why that is?
edit: it could be in the wrong place. I'll have a fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, it's codepen.io/thomasdean/pen/qZGQxK?editors=1010

Comment: check the edited answer just replace the code in codepen with that keep in mind that val is defined inside the loop not outside :) @keeperoftheflame

Comment: I need to go to bed, I'll test it properly tomorrow. Thanks a lot @Peter Darmis

Edit: I had to test it. Still, no button appears to tweet the quote out. What should the HTML look like? Same issue as my first answer to your solution.

Comment: you where writing in your codepen example `<div class="#tweetitout"></div>` that is why it did not show... yes if you are that tired you need to go to bed. Check the last example has full code and is working. Cheers :) @keeperoftheflame

Comment: Oh, the button works, but:

 a) the url is always `http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=`
b) Every time you click the button, it appends a new button to the html, so after ten quotes you've got ten buttons on the screen.

Thanks a lot for your help anyway. Bed it is for me. Don't know where you are but it's quarter to midnight here. Cheers

Comment: `var tweeturl = 'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(val.Quotation + ' - ' + val.Quotee);` this was the fault @keeperoftheflame

Comment: correction use `html()` instead of `append()` @keeperoftheflame

Comment: I sorted the problem out when I woke up this morning - I used solution number 3 given in my initial question - with the tweeturl code in the json.forEach function, it worked. Cheers for all your help.